# string hex to pointer get value

Tags: c++

From the console i am asking for a hexadecimal string to convert to a pointer to reference an item in memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

int char_to_pointer(std::string input);

int main() {
    int sample = 100; // lets say this address is 0xc1f1
    std::string input_;
    std::cout << "addr:" << &sample << std::endl;
    std::cout << "what is the memory address?:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input_;

    unsigned int inp = char_to_pointer(input_);
    std::cout << "imp: " << inp << std::endl;

    Sleep(10000);

    return 0;
}

int char_to_pointer(std::string input) {
    return std::stoul(input, nullptr, 16);
}
```

My problem is that `char_to_pointer` only converts the hex string into a decimal.

this is what i want:

```
input: "0xc1f1"
output: 100
```

Comment: You are aware that a hex value is simply a way for humans to read numbers, and that 0xC1F1 hex and 49649 decimal are **exactly the same value**, right? And that your `char_to_pointer` does absolutely nothing to **read** the address at `0xC1F1` to see what it contains?

Comment: Yes this is for a debugging application i am writing to test disassembled code. @KenWhite Yes, and this is my problem.

Comment: This question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the nature of numbers. Numbers are not sequences of decimal, or hexadecimal, or octal, or balanced ternary digits. The sequences of digits are a way of showing numbers to humans.

Comment: Not only that, but if you are trying to use an address from disassembled code, [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is going to say hello.

Comment: You guys are misunderstanding what i am trying to do. I don't care about the ASLR. I understand Numbers. I am trying to use "human representation" of numbers to reference something in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

int *char_to_pointer(std::string input);

int main() {
    int sample = 100; // lets say this address is 0xc1f1
    std::string input_;
    std::cout << "addr:" << &sample << std::endl;
    std::cout << "what is the memory address?:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input_;

    int *inp = char_to_pointer(input_);
    std::cout << "imp: " << inp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "imp*: " << *inp << std::endl;//This was my solution
    std::cout << "imp&: " << &inp << std::endl;

    Sleep(10000);

    return 0;
}

int *char_to_pointer(std::string input) {
    return (int *)std::stoul(input, nullptr, 16);
}
```